# Conspiracy Theories

Tags: cipher, language

<sup>An entry in [Fortnightly Topic Challenge #35: Restricted Title 1](https://xkcd.com/258/). Title based on this [xkcd](https://xkcd.com/258/).</sup>

---

I think a friend of mine sent me a letter. However, I can't seem to decrypt his message. I'm worried about my potential friend, can you help me decrypt this message?
[image]

I think the writing is written in some form of English, but it's really confusing.

Comment: seems it's runic writing. Is your friend Icelandic?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The message is:

> written in mirror writing, and with shapes that resemble English letters. (e.g. the right-most three letters of the centred first line are mirrored characters for "<ON" = CON)
>  Thanks to Riley for pointing out that including a reflected image would help the answer; I used one when writing but it totally slipped my mind to add to the answer.
>  [image]

Decrypted, it reads:

> CONSPIRACY
>  MY DEAR FRIEND JOE-YOU-KNOW,
>  I NEED YOUR HELP. I HAVE DISCOVERED
>  A CONSPIRACY MOST HEINOUS AND BAD.
>  WHAT I HAVE FOUND WILL SHAKE THE
>  FOUNDATION OF WHAT YOU KNOW
>  ABOUT ICE CREAM. I HAVE LEARNED
>  THAT ICE CREAM COMPANIES ARE
>  TRYING TO TAKE OVER THE WORLD.
>
>  PLEASE HELP ME, OLD FRIEND.
>  I AM IN A MAXIMUM SECURITY
>  PRISON AT THE [BLUE BELL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_Bell_Creameries)
>  HEADQUARTERS. PLEASE, SAVE
>  ME FRIEND. YOU'RE MY ONLY HOPE.
>
>  YOUR FRIEND,
>  RILLOASRON

Comment: You beat me, I was almost done typing it up. +1

I also have an image that might improve your answer. https://i.stack.imgur.com/7cYL5.jpg

Comment: After deciphering that, I bet you'll have to visit your optometrist!

Comment: I can't believe this was decrypted so quickly. I developed this writing system when I was younger to prevent my hand from smearing (I'm left-handed) and to write faster. Good job.