# 50th Puzzle Landmark: My exciting exploits with Adedayo, Prince of Nigeria

Tags: riddle, cipher, enigmatic-puzzle, rhyme, imgur-maze

Today marks a very exciting day for me. Today will be my 50th puzzle on this site, and as such, I've created a challenge the likes of which I have never done before. I hope it to be my most challenging one. It combines many elements to create a story. I encourage partial answers and working together if you'd like.

---

<sub>For this puzzle, I reccommend that you take a look at my previous riddles relating to this, [That is a Battlefield](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/68173/that-is-a-battlefield), [A Lad Named E. Mandala](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/68129/a-lad-named-e-mandala?noredirect=1&lq=1), [Conspiracy Theories](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/66732/conspiracy-theories), and [I received an email from a trusted source which contains flags and symbols](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/68071/i-received-an-email-from-a-trusted-source-which-contains-flags-and-symbols?noredirect=1&lq=1)</sub>

---

For those of you who have been avid readers of this series, you may have wondered what happened to Adedayo, the so-called Prince of Nigeria. When we last left him, he had invited me to meet up with him in Nigeria. I am pleased to say that I had an opportunity to meet up with the young Prince, of whose exploits I have are sure to amaze. Below is my journal that I kept while on our journey. Young Adedayo asked me to encrypt it, lest any unwanted person end up trying to challenge our young hero.

> The Gold 50
>
> D ei rcy qrepr lz wlsp pyzsqeh, rcy idbbhy lz e mykb,
>   Udrc wlsp klqy dk wlsp nypsqeh, wlshh zdkb iy eq wlsp zpdykb.
>   D yvdqr er rcy myadkkdka, ekb er rcy ykb.
>   Di rcypy ucyk wlspy udkkdka, rcy cydacr lz e rpykb.
>   Di klr dk zedhspy, rclsac dz wlspy zedhdka, dhh qspy rl adty wls e cekb.
>
> Di dkcypykrhw qyhzdqc, rcy yndrliy lz qyhz.
>   D myhlka dkqdby qcyhzdqc, d jek my e rwny lz qcyhz.
>   Di klr dkqdby wls, rclsac d ei e nepr lz wlsp zeidhw.
>   D hdgy ndypq, drq rpsy, d jek ilty emlsr zeqr ekb zheqcdhw.
>   D ueqkr rcypy er rcy myadkkdka, klp er rcy ykb.
>
> Di rcypy zlp yejc ekb ytypw lky,
>   Rclsac wls ulkr zdkb iy skbyp rcy qsk.
>   D rpw rl qidhy ytypw bew,
>   Rclsac udrclsr iy, wls ulkr cety isjc rl qew.
>   Di yjqrerdj rl qyy wls.
>
> Di lnyk rl osyqrdlkq, wlshh zdkb iy ucyk pyehdrw cdrq.
>   Di qspnpdqyb qsaayqrdlkq, dhh iegy wls jcyypw ucyk wls jehh dr osdrq.
>   D hdgy blksrq, msr di qspy rcerq kl qspnpdqy.
>   Di dk plmlrq, qyyk ucyk wls lnyk wlsp ywyq.
>   Di ek yvjheierdlk, pdacr myzlpy ek yvnhyrdty.
>
> Zyep iy ucyk wls qyy iy dk rcpyy,
>   Wlshh qyy iy zlp wlsp ytykdka rye.
>   Jlkzsqyb qliyrdiyq zlp iw qdqryp.
>   Iewmy wlshh qyy iy dk e rudqryp.
>   Ebb e r ekb dhh myjliy e rwny lz mpekjc.
>
> Ucer dq rcer kldqy? Bdb iw nclky fsqr ndka?

Hint:

> You're going to want this, https://i.stack.imgur.com

Hint 2:

> Considering that the riddles were what I considered the easy part of this puzzle, I'm going to throw everyone a bone to get things moving along.
> 6 - use it well

Hint 3: (Pretty much necessary to continue the puzzle. Imgur reduced the image quality, making it impossible to continue unless I did this)

> [image]

Hint 4: Here's the highlighted version, as I promised (I made it pretty obvious)

> [image]

Hint 5: Look closer at this area

> [image]

Comment: Conspiracy Theories came first, then flags and symbols, followed by a lad, and then finally That is a Battlefield.

Comment: *Great puzzle!*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using the imgur link @maxathaousand provided and the partial answer by @brian, the image gave me:

> PWY.4UKMD
>  Inverting it back gives:
>  DMKU4.YWP
>  And using the same Caesar Cipher with a shift of 9, we get:
>  UDBL4.PNG

With the hint, I tried all cases until I got:

> https://i.stack.imgur.com/UdbL4.png

With the image:

> [image]

## Partial Answer Part 4.

Using hint 4, we see:

> LQhOJ
>  We use rot13 to get
>  https://i.stack.imgur.com/YDuBW.jpg
>
>  [image]

The typos in the text lead us to:

> https://i.stack.imgur.com/k23IS.jpg
>
>  [image]

## Final Answer Part 5.

Using the hint provided:

> uhzOl
>  We discover that Adedayo has become:
>
>  [image]

Comment: You're the furthest so far, but there is much more to this puzzle. Let me know if I need to upload another hint.

Comment: Good job. Let's see if we can get this solved today.

Comment: Hey, you got it! Good job!

Answer (score 9):

## Partial answer (part 1)

<sub>Thanks to @GentlePurpleRain and @El-Guest for decoding.</sub>

The answers to the decoded riddle are:

> N, I, E, O, and 6.

because

> "The start of your refusal"... → **N**o
>  "...the epitome of self" → **I**
>  "...smile every day ... without me, you won't have much to say..." → people often say "ch**ee**se" when they smile, with the "E" showing the teeth. Without e's, you'd have no t**ee**th
>  "I like donuts ... I'm an exclamation, right before an expletive" → **O** is the shape of a donut. "***O**h, $#%&!*"
>  "Fear me when you see me in three → **6**66 is [known as the Devil's number](https://www.google.com/search?q=666+meaning)

These characters (after trial and error with capitalization) point to the following image:

> Using imgur as the source, we can get the URL https://i.stack.imgur.com/nIEO6.jpg
>  [image: image solution to riddle]

---

## Partial answer (part 2)

Improving on [@practiced_liar's findings](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/68842/24755),

> I noticed that the image contained very faint characters hidden in it. I would imagine these are the characters for the next imgur link.
>  I noticed a distinct "W" on the roots of the tree in the bottom-right corner of the image.
>  Following that, I found an "A" in the middle of the lake.
>  A "v" can be found in the middle of the main tree trunk on the right of the image, near the top corner.
>  From OP's hint, a "Z" can be seen partially overlapping the word "reclaim"
>  [@El-Guest found](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/68795/50th-puzzle-landmark-my-exciting-exploits-with-adedayo-prince-of-nigeria#comment206505_68820) a character later identified to be a 5 under a letter "U" in one of the "Uncle"s, but I still can't find it, hence the lack of a hand-drawn red circle.
>  [image: circled characters]

---

> For convenience, I wrote myself [a <sup><sub>sloppy but functional</sub></sup> script to fetch all permutations of Imgur images](https://jsfiddle.net/maxgmercer/8fLz7jnb/embedded/result). Feel free to use it.

---

## Partial answer (part 3)

> The previous image reveals the characters 5, v, Z, A, W. These combine to give us the next image, at https://i.stack.imgur.com/5vZAW.png.
>  [image: next image]

Comment: Nice job so far. Now the difficult part has began.

Comment: How did you get that picture?

Comment: @ZaniXu, I can explain this one for him, so rot13(hfvat gur uvagf, gb trg A, V, R, B, naq 6, ur gevrq gur inevrgl bs pbzovangvbaf gb nqq gb v.fgnpx.vzthe.pbz hagvy ur sbhaq gur nafjre jnf uggcf://v.fgnpx.vzthe.pbz/aVRB6.cat)

Comment: @Joe-You-Know thanks. Edited to clarify

Comment: You're missing two numbers/letters. Keep at it! :D

Comment: @maxathousand rot13(V guvax gurer'f rvgure n fvk be n avar haqre gur "H" va "Hapyr")...This might be your missing character, although I'm dreading the trial and error to find out the order...

Comment: @El-Guest I was too, so [I wrote a script to do it for me](https://jsfiddle.net/maxgmercer/8fLz7jnb/embedded/result).

Comment: @El-Guest If the 4 I've found so far are correct, neither 6 nor 9 is the missing character.

Comment: @maxathousand that's awesome! I wasn't finding anything using our combined 5 characters though -- are you sure about the fourth one you found? The other ones were clearer but not that one. My digit could be wrong too.

Comment: @Joe-You-Know can you tell us anything regarding the two new characters that maxathousand and I found?

Comment: @El-Guest No, I'm not sure of anything anymore, hahha.

Comment: Wait, which were the two missing characters you found?

Comment: There is only one rot13(i) in this, I don't know why you're script recognized a non existent one. I would look at "Reclaim" more closely.

Comment: He found a second rot13(i), I had found a rot13(fvk be avar). Reclaim helps, though -- are the 5 digits rot13(JNi gjb fvk)?

Comment: @El-Guest, that was a rot13(5, abg n 6), imgur reduced the image quality :|, plus look at "reclaim" a little more closely for the last letter (there are five total for each image in the puzzle).

Comment: @Joe-You-Know, maxathousand called the Reclaim one a 2, but that combined with the 5 under the U is still a problem because rot13(JNi25) or any combination still doesn't work outside of rot13(5jNi2) -- and that appears to be a math problem instead.

Comment: @El-Guest I was mistaken—it was a not the character I thought it was. New image found!

Comment: Hurray, to be fair, it did look like a 2

Comment: This one is interesting, I'm seeing rot13(ebg13 ba gur gerr oenapu va gur abegurnfg pbeare); there may also be a rot13(5 ba gur fgbar va sebag bs gur ubhfr, 7 ba gur vafvqr jnyy, naq B ba gur bhgfvqr jnyy)

Comment: ...It looks like imgur really screwed up this image. One moment guys, I'll reupload this one as a hint at a higher resolution. It'll be impossible to go to the next clue unless I do so.

Comment: Did the third hint help at all? Please let me know.

Comment: @Joe-You-Know It looks larger, but still pretty low quality. Can you verify that all necessary clues are reasonably visible in the new version? Also, I just haven't had much time to look at it since yesterday.

Comment: I can see it with my eyes without zooming in at all (though, I also know where the next clue lies). If this proves too difficult, please let me know. (This is about as high res as I can get the image). If you still struggle, I'll brighten the clue a little bit to make it a little more visible.

Answer (score 7):

#### Partial Answer

Using the imgur link @maxathaousand provided, the image appears to be encoded similarly to

> [Conspiracy Theories](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/66732/conspiracy-theories)

Thus, the image is

> [image: reflected image]

And the message is

> PMY.4NKMD

As for the text on the bottom of the original image, that can be solved using

> A Caesar Cipher, with a shift of 9:
>  with `anvnvkna cx cah juu ljbnb` translating to `remember to try all cases`

Answer (score 6):

#### Partial answer

This appears to be encrypted using

> a simple substitution cipher, with a keyword of **EMJBYZ**:
>
>  `Plaintext:  ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ`
>  `Ciphertext: EMJBYZACDFGHIKLNOPQRSTUVWX`

Decrypted, it gives the following, which is obviously not the final solution:

> I am the start of your refusal, the middle of a bend,
>  With your nose in your perusal, you'll find me as your friend.
>  I exist at the beginning, and at the end.
>  I'm there when you're winning, the height of a trend.
>  I'm not in failure, though if you're failing, I'll sure to give you a hand.
>
>  I'm inherently selfish, the epitome of self.
>  I belong inside shelfish, I can be a type of shelf.
>  I'm not inside you, though I am a part of your family.
>  I like piers, its true, I can move about fast and flashily.
>  I wasn't there at the beginning, nor at the end.
>
>  I'm there for each and every one,
>  Though you wont find me under the sun.
>  I try to smile every day,
>  Though without me, you wont have much to say.
>  I'm ecstatic to see you.
>
>  I'm open to questions, you'll find me when reality hits.
>  I'm surprised suggestions, I'll make you cheery when you call it quits.
>  I like donuts, but I'm sure that's no surprise.
>  I'm in robots, seen when you open your eyes.
>  I'm an exclamation, right before an expletive.
>
>  Fear me when you see me in three,
>  You'll see me for your evening tea.
>  Confused sometimes for my sister.
>  Maybe you'll see me in a twister.
>  Add a t and ill become a type of branch.
>
>  What is that noise? Did my phone just ping?

I thought each stanza might refer to

> a single letter, but my best guesses for each one were
>  **N F E O T**, which seems to be nonsense,
>  although it can be anagrammed to **OFTEN**

Comment: Haha looks like we both got the beginning of it!

Comment: You're doing great so far. The last letter is wrong though. It won't spell a word, but an address/location/image

Comment: Wait, your answer to the second riddle is wrong too. Keep at it. :D

Answer (score 6):

**Partial answer**

Using

> a substitution cipher, with a keyword of **EMJBYZ**:

It gives the following:

> I am the start of your refusal, the middle of a bend,
>  With your nose in your perusal, you'll find me as your friend.
>  I exist at the beginning, and at the end.
>  I'm there when you're winning, the height of a trend.
>  I'm not in failure, though if you're failing, I'll sure to give you a hand.
>
>  I'm inherently selfish, the epitome of self.
>  I belong inside shelfish, I can be a type of shelf.
>  I'm not inside you, though I am a part of your family.
>  I like piers, its true, I can move about fast and flashily.
>  I wasn't there at the beginning, nor at the end.
>
>  I'm there for each and every one,
>  Though you wont find me under the sun.
>  I try to smile every day,
>  Though without me, you wont have much to say.
>  I'm ecstatic to see you.
>
>  I'm open to questions, you'll find me when reality hits.
>  I'm surprised suggestions, I'll make you cheery when you call it quits.
>  I like donuts, but I'm sure that's no surprise.
>  I'm in robots, seen when you open your eyes.
>  I'm an exclamation, right before an expletive.
>
>  Fear me when you see me in three,
>  You'll see me for your evening tea.
>  Confused sometimes for my sister.
>  Maybe you'll see me in a twister.
>  Add a t and ill become a type of branch.
>
>  What is that noise? Did my phone just ping?

I think that (@GentlePurpleRain)

> Each stanza is for one letter, with the letters being:
>  **N I E O T** (T is wrong)

Comment: You've got the second riddle right. P.S. The last one isn't necessarily a letter...

Comment: I KNEW IT!!!! :DDDDD

Comment: @Joe-You-Know Do I need Imgur yet?

Comment: Not quite yet. You'll need it if you find the last riddle though.

Answer (score 3):

Partial answer: solving the substitution cipher, I guessed that

> "UCER" = "WHAT",

And with a few more choice letters, the riddle is:

> I am the start of your refusal, the middle of a bend, 
>  With your nose in your perusal, you'll find me as your friend. 
>  I exist at the beginning, and at the end. 
>  I'm there when you're winning, the height of a trend. 
>  I'm not in failure, though if you're failing, I'll sure to give you a hand. 
>  
>  I'm inherently selfish, the epitome of self. 
>  I belong inside shelfish, I can be a type of shelf. 
>  I'm not inside you, though I am a part of your family. 
>  I like piers, it's true, I can move about fast and flashily. 
>  I wasn't there at the beginning, nor at the end. 
>  
>  I'm there for each and every one, 
>  Though you wont find me under the sun. 
>  I try to smile every day, 
>  Though without me, you wont have much to say. 
>  I'm ecstatic to see you. 
>  
>  I'm open to questions, you'll find me when reality hits. 
>  I'm surprised suggestions, I'll make you cheery when you call it quits. 
>  I like donuts, but I'm sure that's no surprise. 
>  I'm in robots, seen when you open your eyes. 
>  I'm an exclamation, right before an expletive. 
>  
>  Fear me when you see me in three, 
>  You'll see me for your evening tea. 
>  Confused sometimes for my sister. 
>  Maybe you'll see me in a twister. 
>  Add a t and I'll become a type of branch. 
>  
>  What is that noise? Did my phone just ping?

Because of the imgur-maze tag, I think that

> Each stanza might lead to its own imgur URL, and the stanzas might give clues as to the letters to use.

The first stanza could be

> R (start of refusal) EN (middle of bend) B (start of beginning) D (end of end) W (in winning, not in failure, but will help); therefore...RENBDW?

**Partial Answer: Part 5**

> In regards to hint 5, it appears that there are letters written in differently coloured pixels in the map image. They appear to lead to [**uhz01**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uhz01.jpg), but this is not the correct sequence of letters. There is also a line across one of the O's in the street name that I don't know how to decipher.

Comment: You're doing great so far, but your answers to the riddles are wrong. You may want to look at GentlePurpleRain's answer for some help there (but even he has one of them wrong).

Comment: You're on the right path. Keep at it! :D

Comment: Are the letters right? I wasn't certain about reading them but they looked pretty clear! :)

Comment: I'm pretty sure they are (they aren't sequential).